Module warning Angular themes should be created from a map
I just upgraded from Angular v12 to v17 and I'm having some issues with styling. I'm not sure if the following warning points out the root cause or not, but I thought I would post it here to get your opinion (bear with me, I'm very new to Angular).
Error:

[webpack-dev-server] WARNING in ./src/styles.scss?ngGlobalStyle (./src/styles.scss.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[0].oneOf[0].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[0].oneOf[0].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[1].use[0]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].rules[1].use[1]!./src/styles.scss?ngGlobalStyle)
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Angular Material themes should be created from a map containing the keys "color", "typography", and "density". The color value should be a map containing the palette values for "primary", "accent", and "warn". See https://material.angular.io/guide/theming for more information.
node_modules@angular\material\core\theming_theming.scss 183:5  define-light-theme()
src\app\styles\colors\palettes.scss 9:16                         @import
src\app\styles\theme.scss 39:9                                   @import
src\styles.scss 2:9

Package.json
{
    "name": "WMRPD",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "echo Starting... && ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "test:ChromeHeadless": "ng test --watch=false --source-map=false --code-coverage --browsers=MyHeadlessChrome",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e",
        "dev:ssr": "ng run ClientApp:serve-ssr",
        "serve:ssr": "node dist/ClientApp/server/main.js",
        "build:ssr": "ng build --configuration production && ng run ClientApp:server:production",
        "prerender": "ng run ClientApp:prerender"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^17.3.6",
        "@angular/cdk": "^17.3.6",
        "@angular/common": "^17.3.6",
        "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.6",
        "@angular/core": "^17.3.6",
        "@angular/flex-layout": "^15.0.0-beta.42",
        "@angular/forms": "^17.3.6",
        "@angular/material": "^17.3.6",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.6",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.6",
        "@angular/platform-server": "^17.3.6",
        "@angular/router": "^17.3.6",
        "@angular/ssr": "^17.3.6",
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.24.5",
        "@ng-idle/core": "^14.0.0",
        "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
        "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
        "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
        "jspdf-autotable": "^3.8.2",
        "ng": "^0.0.0",
        "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
        "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
        "tslib": "^2.6.2",
        "update": "^0.7.4",
        "zone.js": "~0.14.5"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.3.6",
        "@angular/cli": "^17.3.6",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.6",
        "@types/jasmine": "^5.1.4",
        "@types/node": "^20.12.7",
        "eslint": "^9.1.1",
        "jasmine-core": "~5.1.2",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
        "karma": "~6.4.3",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
        "karma-cli": "~2.0.0",
        "karma-coverage": "~2.2.1",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
        "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.1.0",
        "protractor": "^7.0.0",
        "ts-node": "~10.9.2",
        "tslint": "^6.1.3",
        "typescript": "^5.4.5"
    }
}

styles.css
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import '../src/app/styles/theme';

/* Material Icons */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url(./assets/icons/maticons.woff2) format('woff2');
}

.material-icons {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 1;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-wrap: normal;
    direction: ltr;
    -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

app-data-grid.custom-column-width{
    th{
        width: 200px!important;
    }
}

theme.scss
@use "sass:map";
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
/*@import '@angular/material/theming';*/
/*@import 'typography';*/
@import 'layout';
@import 'colors/palettes';
@import 'colors/palette-brand';
@import 'controls/controls';

// Include non-theme styles for core.
@include mat.core();

@include mat.all-component-themes($wf-app-theme);


You need to create a theme https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#defining-a-theme
Example from documentation
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

$my-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$indigo-palette, 500);
$my-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$pink-palette, A200, A100, A400);

// The "warn" palette is optional and defaults to red if not specified.
$my-warn: mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette);

$my-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
 color: (
   primary: $my-primary,
   accent: $my-accent,
   warn: $my-warn,
 ),
 typography: mat.define-typography-config(),
 density: 0,
));

@include mat.core-theme($my-theme); //<- or maybe only this is missing $wf-app-theme
@include mat.all-component-themes($my-theme);


It seems like the theme is defined in palettes.scss
`
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@import 'color';
$primary: mat.define-palette($primary-primary);
$accent: mat.define-palette($primary-accent);
$warn: mat.define-palette($primary-warn);
$wf-app-theme: mat.define-light-theme($primary, $accent, $warn);
`

I think all of my colors are applied correctly. I'm having a bunch of positioning issues, though. Ideas?

You only added the color. It is missing typography and density
